Bayesian neural network using tensor flow probability
I am trying to solve a regression problem using a Bayesian convolutional neural network. Now, I need to define the prior and posterior functions. The target variable,y follows a Gaussian mixture distribution, and the input data  to the network is not normally distributed either. Should I define the prior distribution model parameters based on the input  or the output  (the target variable) distribution?

Should I define the prior function parameters based on the target variable distribution for regression problems?

Should I use the Gaussian mixture distribution (GMM) instead of normal at the model's output layer (as shown in the code below) as my target variable follows GMM?
distribution_layer = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
            lambda t: tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=t[..., :1],
                                               scale=1e-3 + tf.math.softplus(0.05 * t[..., 1:]))
        )(output_layer)



